# How do I get the result from login action to check in another component Menu after login success

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

How do I get the result from login.action.js to check status in menu.js ?
Is it possible? I need the status after login success to restrict permissions so that certain status can be used in certain menus.

### login.action.js

```
export const login = (history, credential) => {
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
            dispatch(setLoginStateToFetching());
                let result = await httpClient.post(server.LOGIN_URL, credential);
                console.log(result)
                console.log(result);
                if(result.data.result === OK){
                    localStorage.setItem(server.LOGIN_PASSED,YES)
                    getState().appReducer.app.forceUpdate();

                    history.push('/report')

                    dispatch(setLoginStateToSuccess(result));
                } else {
                    dispatch(setLoginStateToFailed());
                }
    }
}
```

Login values are stored in result. I want to check the status to hide some menus.

### Menu.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter, Link} from "react-router-dom";
import { server } from "../../constants";
import { login } from "./../../actions/login.action";

class Menu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  
    this.state = {
      result:"",
    }
  
  render() {
  
      const {pathname} = this.props.location;
    return (
      <div style={{minHeight:'100hv'}}>
        <aside className="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
          {/* Brand Logo */}
          <a href="index3.html" className="brand-link" style={{textAlign:'center', height:'auto'}}>
            <span className="brand-text font-weight-light">Wash@Me</span>
          </a>
          {/* Sidebar */}
          <div className="sidebar" style={{height:'auto'}}>
            <nav className="mt-2">
              <ul
                className="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column"
                data-widget="treeview"
                role="menu"
                data-accordion="false"
              >
                <li className={pathname === '/report' ? 'nav-item' : null}>
                  <Link to="/report" className="nav-link">
                    <i className="far fa-chart-bar" />
                    <p>
                    &nbsp; Report
                      <span className="right badge badge-danger">New</span>
                    </p>
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li className={pathname === '/revenue' ? 'nav-item' : null}>
                  <Link to="/revenue" className="nav-link">
                    <i className="nav-icon fas fa-th" />
                    <p>&nbsp; รายรับ / Revenue</p>
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li className={pathname === '/expenditure' ? 'nav-item' : null}>
                  <Link to="/expenditure" className="nav-link">
                    <i className="nav-icon fas fa-th" />
                    <p>&nbsp; รายจ่าย / expenditure</p>
                  </Link>
                </li>

                {/* <li className="nav-header">EXAMPLES</li> */}
                <li className={pathname === '/customer' ? 'nav-item' : null}>
                  <Link to="/customer" className="nav-link">
                    <i className="nav-icon fas fa-id-badge" />
                    <p>&nbsp; ลูกค้า / Customer</p>
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li className={pathname === '/stock' ? 'nav-item' : null}>
                  <Link to="/stock" className="nav-link">
                    <i className="nav-icon fas fa-clipboard-list" />
                    <p>&nbsp; สินค้า / Product</p>
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li className={pathname === '/member' ? 'nav-item' : null}>
                  <Link to="/member" className="nav-link">
                    <i className="nav-icon fas fa-user-circle" />
                    <p>&nbsp; พนักงาน / Member</p>
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li className={pathname === '/servicePaged' ? 'nav-item' : null}>
                  <Link to="/servicePaged" className="nav-link" >
                    <i className="nav-icon fas fa-money-check" />
                    <p>&nbsp; อัตราบริการ / Service</p>
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <div
                    // logout
                    onClick={() => {
                      this.props.history.push("/home")
                      localStorage.removeItem(server.LOGIN_PASSED);
                      // // บอกให้มันไปใช้ func update
                      this.props.appReducer.app.forceUpdate();
                    }}
                  >
                    <a href="#" className="nav-link">
                      <i className="nav-icon fas fa-door-open" />
                      <p>Logout</p>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            {/* /.sidebar-menu */}
          </div>
          {/* /.sidebar */}
        </aside>
      </div>
    ); 
  }
}

// export default withRouter(Menu);
const mapStateToProps = ({appReducer}) => ({
  appReducer
})

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  // action
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(Menu))
```

This is my menu file that will be authenticated.

### APP.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Header from "./components/header/header";
import Menu from "./components/menu/menu";
import Footer from "./components/footer/footer";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { server, YES } from "./constants";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { setApp } from "./actions/app.action";


const isLoggedIn = () => {
  return localStorage.getItem(server.LOGIN_PASSED) === YES;
};
const SecuredRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render = {props => isLoggedIn() === true ? (
      <Component {...props} />
    ) : (
      <Redirect to="/login" />
    )
    }
  />
);

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.setApp(this); 
    }
  RedirectToLogin = () => {
    return <Redirect to="/home" />;
  };
render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          {isLoggedIn() && <Header />}
          {isLoggedIn() && <Menu />}
          <Switch>
              <Route component={NotFount} /> 
              <Route path="/stock" component={Stock} />
              <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
              <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/stock-edit/:id" component={StockEdit} />
              <SecuredRoute path="/report" component={Report} />
              <Route exact={true} path="/" component={this.redirectToHome} />
              <Route exact={true} path="*" component={this.redirectToHome} />
          </Switch>
          {isLoggedIn() && <Footer />}
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({});
const mapDispatchToProps = {setApp,};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

This is the router section, I made sure the; login is performed. Some of the components that are required to enter the back of the house

### reducer

```
import {
  HTTP_LOGIN_FETCHING,
  HTTP_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  HTTP_LOGIN_FAILED,
  HTTP_STOCK_EDIT_INITIALED
} from "../constants";

// rxre
const initialState = {
  result: null,
  isFetching: false,
  isError: false,
};

export default (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case HTTP_LOGIN_FETCHING:
      return { ...state, result: null, isFetching: true, isError: false };
    case HTTP_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, result: payload, isFetching: false, isError: false };
    case HTTP_LOGIN_FAILED:
      return { ...state, result: null, isFetching: false, isError: true };
      case HTTP_STOCK_EDIT_INITIALED:
        return { ...state, isInitialed: payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you include the reducers that are called after `setLoginStateToSuccess` please?

Comment: ok I've added an example to an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a [container component](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#implementing-container-components) and `connect` redux state with the `component`. You can then further drill down the redux state through props to children components.
This is perhaps the most popular way to pass redux state to components.

However, there is a new approach of using hooks directly inside the components which is **better**. Check this article by Dan Abramov: [Presentational and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)

So in your case, you need to write a few selectors to select the state. You should use [reduxjs/reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) package which caches selector calls. Then you have to use the `useSelector` hook inside `Menu` or any other components.

```
// rootReducer.js

import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import auth from './auth/reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth,
  // other reducers exported from their respective folders
});

export default rootReducer;


// auth/selectors.js

import {createSelector} from 'reselect';

// 1
export const getAuth = ({auth}) => {
  return auth;
};

// 2

export const getAuthIsFetching = createSelector(
  getAuth,
  (auth) => auth.isFetching,
);

export const getAuthIsError = createSelector(
  getAuth,
  (auth) => auth.isError,
);

export const getAuthResult = createSelector(
  getAuth,
  (auth) => auth.result,
);

// Menu.js
// Note: convert it to functional component to use redux hooks

import React from "react"
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {getAuthIsFetching, getAuthResult} from '../path/to/selectors.js'

const Menu = (props) => {
  const {pathname} = props.location;

  const authIsFetching = useSelector(getAuthIsFetching);
  const authResult = useSelector(getAuthResult);

  return (
    <div style={{minHeight:'100hv'}}>
    // ...
    </div>
  )
}

// SomeOtherComponent.js

import React from "react"
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {getAuthIsFetching} from '...path to selectors.js'

const SomeOtherComponent = (props) => {
  const authIsFetching = useSelector(getAuthIsFetching);

  return (
    <>{authIsFetching ? 'Login in' : 'Done'}</>
  )
}
```